# Extended class issues

Tags: java, subclass

I have had some issues involving code that accesess variables defined in a superclass that were later revised in a child class. Ie

```
  //start of Stat class. Variables in question are defined here. (Name, Level,        Experience, totalXP)
public class Stat {

public static String Name = " ";
    public static int Level = 0;
    public static double Experience = 0;
    public static double totalXP = 0;

    //Sets Name
    public static void setName(String NameIn) {
            Name = NameIn;
    }
    //Sets Level
    public static void setLevel(int LevelIn) {
            Level = LevelIn;
    }
    //Sets Experience
    public static void setExperience(double ExperienceIn) {
            Experience = ExperienceIn;
    }
    //Sets totalXP
    public static void settotalXP(double totalXPIn) {
            totalXP = totalXPIn;
    }


    //Sets up Attributes
    public static void setall() {
            setName("Herp");
            setLevel(1);
            setExperience(0);
            settotalXP(0);


    }



    //Displays a Stat's Attributes
    public static void DisplayLevel() {

            System.out.println(Name);
            System.out.println("Level: " + Level);
            System.out.println(Experience + " out of " + totalXP + " total     experience.");

    }//End of method

    public static void Levelup() {

            if(Experience >= totalXP) {

                    Level++;
                    totalXP = totalXP * 1.3;
                    Experience = 0;

            }//end of if statement

    }//end of Levelup method

}//end of Stat.class





public class Agility extends Stat{

    {//Revisionary Block
            Name = "Agility";
            Level = 1;
            Experience = 0;
            totalXP = 125;
    }



    public static int runnappDodge(int Dodge) {
            Random generator = new Random(10);


            Dodge = generator.nextInt(10);
            if (Dodge == 0) {

                    Player.incomingDMG = 0;

         }//end of if statement
            return Dodge;


            }



//start of the method located on player.class. This prints out " ", 0.0 and 0.0 for all         //of the fields.

public static void checkLevel() {

            System.out.println("You are level: " + Level);
            System.out.println("You have " + experience + " experience out of " +     totalXP + " total experience");
            System.out.println(stat.Attack.Name + " Level: " + stat.Attack.Level + ":     Experience: " + stat.Attack.Experience + "/" + stat.Attack.totalXP);
            System.out.println(stat.Archery.Name +" Level: " + stat.Archery.Level +":     Experience: " + stat.Archery.Experience + "/" + stat.Archery.totalXP);
            System.out.println(stat.Agility.Name +" Level: " + stat.Agility.Level + ":     Experience: " + stat.Agility.Experience + "/" + stat.Agility.totalXP);

    }//end of checkLevel method
```

my full code is here: http://pastebin.com/6nPGwJQe

reddit was no help so I now turn to you. (not that you arent helpful, but I just use reddit more so it is more convenient). I think that my code should be updating the variables in the subclasses but it doesnt. When I refrence the variable it ends up being excactly what it was when defined by super class, in Aaron.name's case, " " rather than "Aaron". I'm not sure if a getter and setter might be useful here, but I appreciate all advice

PS: My first question on stackoverflow!

Edit: Thanks for the feedback. This was example code. The last commenter helped out a lot, but my real code is entirely independent from this. It was to convey an example. So please see the link because that code is really what matters.
Edit 2: Because I can see that one might need to see the structure of my project for imports and references sake, here is an image of my project structure: http://imgur.com/VhDzRrm

Edit 3: No longer does my post use an example that is incorrect, it uses my actual code.

Comment: `Derp` has a field called `name`, and `Aaron` has a field called `Name`. Those are two separate fields.

Comment: How did you compile this? `Aaron.name` should not be compiled, since you do not have object, u can not call non static var

Comment: @elbek It's a warning AFAIK

Comment: @user2658898, is this code compiled without error?

Comment: The topic has a typo: "Extened class issues" (sic).

Comment: Of course this doesn't compile. Please post actual code instead of an incorrect example you developed.

Comment: Apart from the typo, your `public class Aaron` needs to use the correct spelling of the variable `name` - it should be all lowercase, but you have capitalized the letter `N` in your subclass. Furthermore, it's not a static variable so you can't refer to it by `Aaron.name`, you have to create a new instance of `Aaron`, or make it a static variable.

Comment: If I were you, I would study some simple examples of Java inheritance that run and compile, before making your own. You'll have to learn the difference between instance variables and static variables, how to create an object using `new`, and that variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: I don't see any classes named Derp or Aaron in your pastebin. Can you please edit the code in your post to be representative of the problem you are encountering?

Comment: @ktm5124 I got it, but you can suggest an edit to fix.

Comment: I reworded the question so that it hits the marks defined by the users who marked it "off topic"

Answer (score 1):

Java is very clear about case-sensitivity.  Since you have extended the Derp class your Aaron class now has two String fields. name and Name.  That is why it is displaying nothing, because you have instantiated your name String to "".  if you replaced it with Aaron.Name you will have what you are looking for.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, you are correct.  And I was wrong.  He should instead be using access modifiers for his variables and use getters, setters and constructors.

Comment: This is not my actual code. I didnt realize that I had Name and name, I wanted just name. If someone would be so kind as to look at the actual code which has been compiled successfully, then report back it would be very helpful

Comment: @Aaron So, you are having trouble with the checkLevel() method?  It looks like you are trying to get to subclasses through the dot operator.  You do not need to do that.  You can simply call the class that you need if the classes are all in the same package.  I.E. Agility.Name

Comment: Yes, but checkLevel() method is located on main.Player class and the stats are in the stat package. Do you suggest restructuring my project to compensate?

Comment: please see the link for an image of my project structure: http://imgur.com/VhDzRrm

Comment: You can import the stat package into the Player.Java file. I also must say that for your own sanity and to get used to conventions, start right now playing with access modifiers and getters and setters.  It will save you tonnes of headache later.

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly take this advice

Answer (score 0):

I'll go over a few issues in your code.

First obviously, it doesn't compile, as others have pointed out. You should take your actual code and strip out anything that's not germane to the problem. Keep stripping until your sample code is as small as what you posted here, but make sure it still compiles. See http://sscce.org/

Odds are, you'll find the bug as you go, in which case post your own answer to the question (yes, you can do that). If not, edit your question with the actual code.

Now, to address your issues:

There was no need to use an anonymous constructor for **Aaron**. It should have been

```
public class Aaron extends Derp {
    public Aaron() { Name = "Aaron"; IQ = 10; }
}
```

(Something tells me you're coming from a C++ background.)

"name" is an instance variable, which means that it only exists as part of an object of type **Derp** (or **Aaron**).  You first need to create an object, then reference *that*.

```
public static void main() {
    Aaron aaron = new Aaron();
    System.out.println("Hi, my name is: " + aaron.name + "!\n");
}
```

You could also have made **name** a class variable:

```
static String name = " ";
```

but there's no good way to override that variable in a subclass, so we won't go there.

One final nit: you didn't need that "\n" in the println() call, since that function appends a newline for you.